# Extracting values dynamically from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data-frame of p-values:

```
> newcor
   i1 i4 i3 i2
i1 NA  0  0  0
i4  0 NA  0  0
i3  0  0 NA  0
i2  0  0  0 NA
```

I also have the following corresponding character strings:

```
> newDV
[1] "i1"
> newIV
[1] "i4" "i3" "i2"
```

I am trying to write code that automates it so a data frame is returned with newDV as the only row and newIV as the corresponding columns,such as:

```
> newcor
   i1 i4 i3 i2
i1 NA  0  0  0
```

I would also like newDV with newDV removed if possible so the final outcome is:

```
> newcor
   i4 i3 i2
i1  0  0  0
```

Comment: @Frank That worked, feel free to propose that as an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your data is a matrix

```
set.seed(1)
m <- diag(4)
dimnames(m) <- list( sample(letters[1:4]), sample(LETTERS[1:4]) )
#   A C B D
# b 1 0 0 0
# d 0 1 0 0
# c 0 0 1 0
# a 0 0 0 1
```

If so, just use `[` to subset:

```
myrows = "c"
mycols = c("B","A")
m[myrows, mycols, drop=FALSE]
#   B A
# c 1 0
```

`drop=FALSE` ensures that the result is still a matrix with row and col names.

Comment: Perfect that worked thank you very much!  I will accept as soon as I can.  However, the data is actually a data frame as I made it such, but the code still works.  Thanks!